# BBcode -> HTML parsing makeup issue

Tags: html, nested, bbcode

I am an amateur so sorry if the answer is obvious. As part of my own education I am trying to make a text editor using the BBcode principle. With "HTML/JS/JQuery/Ajax/PHP/Regex" and I am relatively far ahead. However I keep running into a problem regards to style. Since BBcode has variable starting and editing and values such as "[color=#1234af]" or "[size=12]" I cannot work with CSS (I think).
Now the problem is I am limited to "`<span style=""></span>`"

Here is the only way I know how to parse it...

```
$ColorBB[] = '`\[color\=(([a-fA-F]|\d){6})\](.*?)\[\/color\]`si';
$ColorHTML[] = '<span style="color:#\\1">\\3</span>';

$SizeBB[] = '`\[size\=([0-9]{1,2})\](.*?)\[\/size\]`si';
$SizeHTML[] = '<span style="font-size:#\\1">\\2</span>';

$FontBB[] = '`\[font\=([a-zA-Z]{4,7})\](.*?)\[\/size\]`si';
$SizeHTML[] = '<span class="\\1">\\2</span>';
```

The problem is that you can only use 1 the end of [/color] [/size] [/font] are all "`</span>`"

```
[color=FFA929]Color[size=30]Size and color[/color]Size[/size]
```

This would result in

```
<span style="color:FFA929;">Color<span style="font-size:30;">Size and Color</span>size</span>
```

And the "span" of "[/color]" would close the [size] where I do not want it.

From googling I could only see that it has to do with nesting or something.
It's been 9 days and still haven't found a solution.

Comment: A `span` nested within a `span` is valid HTML, or maybe that’s not the issue you’re describing?

Comment: I have tried to explain it better. I hope someone has a answer.